# Method within React functional component

Tags: reactjs

Hello I had to add a method inside a component, that was stateless functional component. Now I am wondering if it can stay like this or should it be a class component now. My component:

```
const Pagination = ({ changePage }) => {
  function changePageNumber(event) {
    changePage(event.currentTarget.dataset.num);
  }
  return (
      <button
          className={css.button}
          data-num={num}
          onClick={changePageNumber}
        >
          {num}
        </button>
  );
};
```

Can it be like this?

Answer (score 0):

`changePageNumber` is a function not a method. It is perfectly fine to stay there. It is there as a utility/helper function for that `Pagination` component. Such functions can be deployed to improve the readability of the code. Current state of your code perfectly fine.

Also you don't need to turn it into **Class components**, we use them when we think we need to store state, **not to store methods**.

Comment: and isn't it bad because of efficiency? Isn't the same as function inside render in class component?

Comment: @heisenberg7584 There is nothing about performance/efficiency in this usecase of your post.

Comment: @ArupRakshit - but isn't it like this - in functional component functions will be renedered each time the component is rendered and in class component methods can be stored above render method so just the component will be rendered and the method reference is the same so about performance it is better?

Comment: @jake-ferguson a performance should not be a concern when you have a function like `changePageNumber` be a method or a function. So to answer you it really depends on what you have right now. The way OP thought about to be concerned and make it a class component is not something he needs to be concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write methods like this. Also you can use arrow functions, like:

```
const Pagination = ({ changePage }) => {
  const changePageNumber = event => {
    changePage(event.currentTarget.dataset.num);
  }
  return (
    <button
        className={css.button}
        data-num={num}
        onClick={changePageNumber}
     >
       {num}
     </button>
  );
};
```

Bonus: It's not necessary to name component that exported default, just:

```
export default ({ changePage }) => {
...
}
```

And in another file:

```
import AnyName from './Pagination'
```

Comment: Having a name helps while debugging, because it is being used a `displayName` for that function.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it to be like

```
     const changePageNumber = (event) = () => {
        changePage(event.currentTarget.dataset.num);
      }
      const Pagination = ({ changePage }) => {

      return (
          <button
              className={css.button}
              data-num={num}
              onClick={changePageNumber}
            >
              {num}
            </button>
         );
      };
```

Comment: why to do it like this ?